# Can the UNIX command tree display only directories matching a pattern?

Tags: shell, command-line, tree

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to get the UNIX command `tree` to display only directories that match a specific pattern.

```
% tree -d tstdir -P '*qm*' -L 1
tstdir
|-- d1
|-- d2
|-- qm1
|-- qm2
`-- qm3

5 directories
```

The **man page** shows this bit about the switch.

> -P pattern
>                 List only those files that match the wild-card pattern.  Note: you must use the -a option to also consider those files
>   beginning with a dot `.' for
>                 matching.  Valid wildcard operators are`*' (any zero or more characters), `?' (any single character),`[...]' (any single
>   character listed between
>                 brackets (optional - (dash) for character range may be used: ex: [A-Z]), and `[^...]' (any single character not listed in
>   brackets) and`|'  sepa‐
>                 rates alternate patterns.

I'm assuming that the bit about **...List only those files...** is the issue. Am I correct in my interpretation that this switch will only pattern match on files and **NOT** directories?

Comment: what you want to accomplish ? have you tried `find tstdir/ -type d -iname "qm*"`  or `tree  -I "d*" -d tstdir/`

Comment: Directories are technically also files, but a special kind of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone mentioned on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13997742/33204) in the `trees` man page that this is why the `-P` switch doesn't exclude things that don't match the pattern.

```
BUGS
   Tree  does not prune "empty" directories when the -P and -I options are
   used.  Tree prints directories as it comes to them, so  cannot  accumu‐
   late  information  on files and directories beneath the directory it is
   printing.
```

So it doesn't appear to be possible to get `tree` to filter its output using the -P switch.

**EDIT #1**

From a question I had posted on SO that got closed. Someone, [@fhauri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1765658/f-hauri), had posted the following information as alternative ways to accomplish what I was trying to do with the `tree` command. I'm adding them to my answer here for completeness.

`-d` switch ask to **not** print files:

```
    -d     List directories only.
```

So if you WANT use this, you could:

```
tree tstdir -P '*qm*' -L 1 | grep -B1 -- '-- .*qm'
|-- id1
|   `-- aqm_P1800-id1.0200.bin
--
|-- id165
|   `-- aqm_P1800-id165.0200.bin
|-- id166
|   `-- aqm_P1800-id166.0200.bin
--
|-- id17
|   `-- aqm_P1800-id17.0200.bin
--
|-- id18
|   `-- aqm_P1800-id18.0200.bin
--
|-- id2
|   `-- aqm_P1800-id2.0200.bin
```

At all, if you use `-L 1`,

```
   -L level
          Max display depth of the directory tree.
```

you could better use (in bash) this syntax:

```
cd tstdir
echo */*qm*
```

or

```
printf "%s\n" */*qm*
```

and if only dir is needed:

```
printf "%s\n" */*qm* | sed 's|/.*$||' | uniq
```

At all, you could do this very quickly if *pure bash*:

```
declare -A array;for file in  */*qm* ;do array[${file%/*}]='';done;echo "${!array[@]}"
```

This could be explained:

```
cd tstdir
declare -A array          # Declare associative array, (named ``array'')
for file in  */*qm* ;do   # For each *qm* in a subdirectory from there
    array[${file%/*}]=''  # Set a entry in array named as directory, containing nothing
  done
echo "${!array[@]}"         # print each entrys in array.
```

... if there is no file matching pattern, result would display `*`.
so for perfect the job, there left to do:

```
resultList=("${!array[@]}")
[ -d "$resultList" ] || unset $resultList
```

(This would be a lot quicker than

```
declare -A array
for file in  */*qm*; do
    [ "$file" == "*/*qm*" ] || array[${file%/*}]=''
  done
echo "${!array[@]}"
```

)

Answer (score 2):

There's no way for `tree` to do this on its own. Patterns are not applied to directories, only files.

However, you can easily accomplish what you want by getting the directory listing with `tree`, and then applying the match pattern with `grep`.

```
tree -d tstdir -L 1 | grep '*qm*'
```

Comment: This messes up the output from tree though.

Comment: @sim - In what way?

Comment: The ASCII line graphics that show the directory structure. Admittedly this isn't a huge deal but I thought I'd mention it.